# In R, fitting the same model on wide format vs long (tidy) format dataframes with the lm() function

Tags: r, tidyverse, lm, long-format-data, wide-format-data

I'm working on the publicly available dataset 'FEV.dat' on [this
page](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/%7Eaa/glm/data) (raw data
[here](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/%7Eaa/glm/data/FEV.dat)) and am trying to fit a
linear model. I can do this without issue when the data is in wide format, but
once I put it into a long format, I don't know how to fit the same model.

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)

fev <- read.table("FEV.dat", header=T)
```

```
> head(fev)
  patient base fev1 fev2 fev3 fev4 fev5 fev6 fev7 fev8 drug
1       1 2.46 2.68 2.76 2.50 2.30 2.14 2.40 2.33 2.20    a
2       2 3.50 3.95 3.65 2.93 2.53 3.04 3.37 3.14 2.62    a
3       3 1.96 2.28 2.34 2.29 2.43 2.06 2.18 2.28 2.29    a
4       4 3.44 4.08 3.87 3.79 3.30 3.80 3.24 2.98 2.91    a
5       5 2.80 4.09 3.90 3.54 3.35 3.15 3.23 3.46 3.27    a
6       6 2.36 3.79 3.97 3.78 3.69 3.31 2.83 2.72 3.00    a
```

```
# fit a simple model using the variable 'base' to predict the variable 'fev1'
fit.base <- lm(fev1 ~ 1 + base, data=fev)
```

Now I put the data set into a long format and make it a tidy dataframe
(possibly not in the most efficient way, as I'm new to R). Therefore the
variables 'base', 'fev1', 'fev2' ... 'fev8' are now levels of a factor 'time':

```
fev_long <- fev %>% 
    pivot_longer(
     base:fev8,
     names_to="time",
     values_to="score"
    )

fev_tidy <- as_tibble(fev_long)
fev_tidy$drug <- as.factor(fev_tidy$drug)
fev_tidy$time <- as.factor(fev_tidy$time)
```

```
> fev_tidy
# A tibble: 648 x 4
   patient drug  time  score
     <int> <fct> <fct> <dbl>
 1       1 a     base   2.46
 2       1 a     fev1   2.68
 3       1 a     fev2   2.76
 4       1 a     fev3   2.5
 5       1 a     fev4   2.3
 6       1 a     fev5   2.14
 7       1 a     fev6   2.4
 8       1 a     fev7   2.33
 9       1 a     fev8   2.2
10       2 a     base   3.5
# … with 638 more rows
```

What I want to know, is how to use the scores corresponding to the 'base' level
of the 'time' factor to predict the scores corresponding to the 'fev1' level of
the 'time' factor, now that the data is in long (and tidy) format?

I've tried a few things without success and can't find the answer on google.
While I can do the analysis with the data in wide format.

Comment: In this case the wide format is what you want.  Otherwise you'll be doing:  fit.base <-lm(fev_tidy[time == "fev1"]$score ~ 1 + fev_tidy[time ==  "base"]$score)

Comment: @BrianMontgomery Ah ok that helps - I read more about tidy data and learned that just because data is in wide format doesn't necessarily mean it's not in tidy format. Am I right in thinking the data was already in tidy format before I lengthened it? (I updated the question so as not confuse others with incorrect statements about what was wide, long, and tidy)

Comment: Yes.  Exactly.  The data was already tidy and therefore in the best form to analyze.

Comment: @BrianMontgomery Great thanks for letting me know! If you want to put those comments into an answer I'll accept and upvote.